# Download Documentation in XCode 7.2

Tags: xcode

When I try to download documentation in XCode 7.2 with Preferences -> Downloads, I get the error message

```
Could not download and install iOS 9.2 Documentation. Don't know how to install package with extension  from file:///Users/gerd/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads/com.apple.adc.documentation.iOS-92.3.. Downloaded from {
dependencies =     (
);
fileSize = 1071665369;
identifier = "com.apple.adc.documentation.iOS";
name = "iOS 9.2 Documentation";
source = "https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Documentation/Xcode_7.2_beta_2_DocSets/03143046A.dmg";
userInfo =     {
    ActivationPredicate = "7.2.0 >= '7.2'";
    Category = Documentation;
    IconType = IDEDownloadablesTypeDocSet;
    InstallPrefix = "/Users/gerd/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets";
    InstalledIfAllReceiptsArePresentOrNewer =         {
        "com.apple.pkg.7.0.iOSDocset" = "10.9.0.0.1.1446334486";
    };
    RequiresADCAuthentication = 1;
    Summary = "My description of content";
};
version = "92.3";
}.
```

Is there any workaround?

Comment: This hardly seems like a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: looks like they're still referencing the beta:
source = "…/Xcode_7.2_beta_2_DocSets/03143046A.dmg";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue has been resolved by Apple. It's working now.